# Regex returning inconsistent results on the same string

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression that is supposed to match the beginnings of certain paragraphs in some files I have. It works when I run it on a smaller version of the file, but when I run it on the whole file it picks up an excluded \r on the 4th match, and I'm not sure why.

Heres the method:

```
    def getRowTitles(self):
            rowNames = []
            pattern = r'([^\r].{1,4}\(.*?\)[^_]*?)'
            count = 0
            found = re.search(pattern, self.read)
            toLoopThrough = self.read
            while found:
                rowNames.append(found.group().strip())
                count = toLoopThrough.find(found.group())
                toLoopThrough = toLoopThrough[count + len(found.group()):]
                found = re.search(pattern, toLoopThrough)
            return rowNames
```

the beginning of the file looks like this:

```
            Average per group       sum per group       n per group     stdev per group     Log 2   p-value Individual Areas normalised by weight                                   
            WT  OX  WT  OX  WT  OX  WT  OX  OX/WT       WT              OX
```

lipid polarity @ retention time Class   Class   SubClass                                            C1378   C1383   C1387   C1513   C1377   C1381   C1382   C1389   C1397   C1519
Lipids with p-values <0.05
Cardiolipin
CL(23:4/24:1/20:3/18:1)_NEG@43.978  CL  Cardiolipin Cardiolipin 58259.7396  108709.9208 233038.9584 652259.5249 4   6   29064.41359 19088.852   0.899912448 0.030160222 3.56E+04    9.88E+04    5.99E+04    3.88E+04    9.92E+04    1.18E+05    1.14E+05    1.31E+05    7.55E+04    1.15E+05
Glycosphingolipids
Cer(d18:2/22:1)_NEG@45.079  Cer Glycosphingolipids  Ceramides   73771.99705 172457.0264 295087.9882 1034742.159 4   6   23692.94535 68679.54864 1.225091714 0.015442582 7.77E+04    7.05E+04    4.47E+04    1.02E+05    1.49E+05    3.01E+05    1.85E+05    1.04E+05    1.35E+05    1.60E+05
Neutral glycerolipid
DG(16:0/22:6)_POS@45.696    DG  Neutral glycerolipid    diglyceride 1970578.151 620552.4835 7882312.604 3723314.901 4   6   642432.36   508282.8967 -1.666993829    0.01447318  1.53E+06    1.69E+06    2.92E+06    1.74E+06    1.18E+06    3.25E+05    1.03E+06    1.53E+05    1.01E+06    2.57E+04
TG(16:1/16:1/18:2)_POS@52.725   TG  Neutral glycerolipid    triglyceride    205875394.4 129414602.1 823501577.5 776487612.3 4   6   21098256.62 66163733.32 -0.669771005    0.036476709 2.03E+08    1.84E+08    2.35E+08    2.02E+08    1.69E+08    1.26E+08    1.72E+08    1.33E+08    1.75E+08    1.36E+06

If the file is only as long as this excerpt, the method returns a list that looks like ['CL(23:4/24:1/20:3/18:1)', 'Cer(d18:2/22:1)', 'DG(16:0/22:6)', 'TG(16:1/16:1/18:2)'], but if the file is longer it messes up and gives me ['CL(23:4/24:1/20:3/18:1)', 'Cer(d18:2/22:1)', 'DG(16:0/22:6)', '04\rTG(16:1/16:1/18:2)']

If anyone knows why these cases are any different that'd be super helpful.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools in the editor to make your question more readable.  The lower portion is all plaintext and it's difficult to decypher what parts are the input file and what parts are the terminal output.  Thanks!

Comment: garbage in, garbage out; probably because the file with the probably has duplicated `\r` most likely, either way this is not something that anyone here can solve. a text editor like Sublime Text 3 ( not notepad.exe ) can show you *invisible* characters.

Comment: This `[^_]*?` at the end of the expression will never match anything. Even if it could, it will match all linebreaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some basic diagnostic's,

try something like this to start.

`(?m-s)^(.{1,5}\(.*?\))`

Leave out `[^_]*?` because it says don't match anything unless it has to.

Here is the above without using modifiers.

`(?:^|\r?\n)([^\r\n]{1,5}\([^\r\n]*?\))`

or, the universal version

`(?:^|\r?\n|\r)([^\r\n]{1,5}\([^\r\n]*?\))`

Comment: Thanks, the last one of your suggestions works perfectly!

Comment: @JonahNeugeboren - Great! If it worked for you, consider accepting (check) and upvoting.